# Calculated View Object Attribute not able to be used in JSPX page

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper, oracle-fusion-middleware

Hello I have a View Object "Validationerrortallygroupsview"  In this VO I have a calculated attribute that is generated by a join in the query.  The calculated attribute is RuleName1 (RULE_NAME alias).

Here is where I show the attributes:

[image: View Object Attributes]

The SQL query that backs this View Object has a join with another table and this join is what generates this extra RULE_NAME attribute:

[image: SQL Query that backs View Object]

The SQL Query tests fine and everything but when I go to my JSPX page to actually reference this attribute using EL, the new attribute doesn't show up in the variable.

I have a row variable that is simply used to iterate through the bindings for a table Control, ruleName1 is not an element that I can choose off of that variable, I can only choose the Attributes that were defined originally as part of the Entity:

[image: EL showing I can only choose attributes that are part of original entity, the calculated attribute doesn't show up...]

Answer (score 1):

Can you check the tree binding whether the attribute "RuleName1" is present or not ? If not , you may need to refresh the data control once and add it to attribute list of the tree binding .

Comment: Hi Sid,  This was indeed an issue.  I have gone in the tree binding associated to the PageDef of interest and moved the RuleName1 from "Available attributes" to "Display Attributes".  So now I can reference the attribute in the JSPX EL, however it always comes up blank in the resulting table.  I have double checked my VO query and even ran that query against the actual DB to make sure the value came back non-empty from DB.  One thing that stood out to me was that in the Attribute definition the RuleName1 "Entity Usage" is blank, shouldn't it be Transient?  Anything else I can look at?

Answer (score 0):

Drag&Drop that property from your DataControl, or better the whole form/table in a clean page to see what is going on.